# Regex expression for text

Tags: c#, regex

How do I write regex expression for text where first two characters are letters, but the rest of characters are numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well assuming that is the only requriment somthing like this.

```
[a-zA-Z]{2,2}\d+
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be:

```
\[A-Za-z]{2}\d+
```

Schimples!

Comment: Or `\w{2}\d*` in case ex `he` is allowed.

Comment: @lasseespeholt - thats actually how I originally had this regex before I edited it. I assume at least 1 numeric is required. You're absolutely right if the number part is optional `*` would be better as this matches 0 or more numbers.

Comment: \w allows 0-9 and underscores as well as letters, so this would not enforce the requirement that the first 2 characters are letters only

Comment: @Brian - bah, you're right. Serves me right for thinking I can remember regex without a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt="aa4"; //for instance.

      string re1="([a-zA-Z])";  
      string re2="([a-zA-Z])";  
      string re3="(\\d+)";  

      Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String w1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String w2=m.Groups[2].ToString();
            String d1=m.Groups[3].ToString();
            Console.Write("("+w1.ToString()+")"+"("+w2.ToString()+")"+"("+d1.ToString()+")"+"\n");
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```